# Class type arrays in other classes in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, nested

I have a problem with inputing values into arrays which are placed inside the class. I try to do this by using methods. My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//class for items
class Item{
string name;
int amount;
public:
Item();
Item(string, int);

//returns the name of an item
string getName(){
    return name;
}
//sets name for items
void setName(string name){
    this->name = name;
}

//returns the amount of items
int getAmount(){
    return amount;
}
//sets the amount for items
void setAmount(int amount){
    this->amount = amount;
}
};

//first constructor
Item::Item(){
name="none";
amount=0;
}

//second constructor
Item::Item(string name, int amount){
this->name=name;
this->amount=amount;
}

//class for hero with "Items" array
class Hero{
string name;
Item inventory[20];
public:
Hero();
Hero(string);

//returns the name of the hero
string getName(){
    return name;
}
//sets the name for the hero
void setName(string name){
        this->name = name;
}
};

//first constructor
Hero::Hero(){
name="none";
}

//second constructor
Hero::Hero(string name){
this->name=name;
}

int main() {
Hero firsthero;
string name;
//giving hero the name
cout<<"Input name: ";
cin>>name;
firsthero.setName(name);
//printing the hero's name
cout<<firsthero.getName()<<endl;
//setting the items;
Item sword;
Item armor;
Item potion;
//setting items' values;
sword.setName("sword");
sword.setAmount(1);
armor.setName("armor");
armor.setAmount(1);
potion.setName("potion");
potion.setAmount(3);
//gives these items into array "inventory" in the "firsthero" class
return 0;
}
```

I would like to add items "sword", "armor" and "potion" into firsthero, however I have not found a way to write a method in "Hero" which would allow me to do that. I could just load them directly by making its fields public, but I read that it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having an array of size 20 in your `Hero` class, try using a `std::vector`. If you have a `addItem` method for `Hero`, you can simply do a check of whether or not the hero can hold anymore items (check `inventory.size()` against some constant you create, maybe something like `MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE`).

So something like this:

```
std::vector<Item> inventory;
const int MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE = 20;
...

//returns true if it successfully added the item, false otherwise
bool Hero::addItem(Item i) {
    if(inventory.size < MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE) {
        inventory.push_back(i);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

...

hero.addItem(sword);
hero.addItem(armor);
hero.addItem(potion);
```

Comment: If he has a constant maximum size, `std::array` is a better choice than `std::vector`.  If he were to screw up the logic with the bounds checking, a vector will happily let him keep adding elements (which may or may not cause problems later).  array will give an out of bounds exception (at least if he uses the `at` method)

Comment: True, but if somewhere down the line he wishes to remove `Item`s at random, he would then have to keep track of 'unfilled' indices within the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an accessor method for your items:

```
class Hero
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::array<Item, 20> inventory; // use the array container instead of C-style arrays
    unsigned int itemCount;

public:
    Hero() : itemCount(0) {}
    Hero(string n) : name(n), itemCount(0) {}

    //returns the name of the hero
    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    //sets the name for the hero
    void setName(const std::string& name)
    {
        this->name = name;
    }

    const Item& getItem(int i) const { return inventory[i]; } // NOTE:  you may want some bounds checking here, but this is basically what you are doing
    Item& getItem(int i) { return inventory[i]; } // to update a particular item

    void addItem(const Item& item) { inventory[itemCount++] = i; } // same with bounds checking here
};
```